# Conditioning a conditional event on another variable - syntax

Tags: probability

Say that I have events $A$ and $B$, and the conditional probability $P(A|B)$. If we define $C$ to be the event $A|B$, then we can write $P(A|B) = P(C)$.

If we know want to write $P(C|D)$, how would we substitute $A|B$ for $C$ in this case? I've never seen the notation $P(A|B|D)$ before and this doesn't seem to make sense. Would it be $P(A|B,D)$ instead?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111024/double-conditional-in-a-probability

Comment: Hmm I see, so in this case it's simply $P(A|B,D)$?

Comment: Basically. Imagine that I am only happy (event $A$) if the pool is open ($B$) and the sun is out ($C$). Then $P(A) = P(A|B,C)$. But now imagine the pool is only open if it's sunny out. For $A$, I still need $B$ and $C$, but $B$ can only happen if $C$ happens anyway. So $P(A) = P(A|(B|C)) = P(A|B,C)$

Comment: @jeremy909 Ah I see. So in this case $P(B|C) = P(B, C)$?

Comment: @jeremy909 What if we had a more general case where $P(B|C) \neq P(B,C)$?

Comment: Sorry. This is not the case where $P(B|C) = P(B,C)$. This is the case $P(A|B,C) = P(A|(B|C)),$ which is always, as can be seen in the derivations in the link.